# ASP.NET Core IdentityServer4 - Claims List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, identityserver4

I want to create asp.net core app with Identity management. Now I need give management of Users-Roles-Claims to the user. But There is now Claims table in Database. I have only following tables:

[image]

Before this I used Role-Rights base identity, I created this custom. So I had everything in database. I could fetch Rights List, gave this list to a Role. My database was as follow:

[image]

But in this Identity I can't do this logic.

Please tell me how to create management of Identity for such stuation.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UserManager (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) for management your identity.

Some links: http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-identity-role-claims